# VBA - An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call

Tags: vba, email, outlook, basic

I want to send an email via code using Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications. The Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library is checked under Tools/References. The code compiles error-free. The code works fine on two different machines, but when I test it on a third machine, it gives the error when executing line #2.

```
Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
Set email = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    email.To = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
    email.Subject = "Subject"
    email.Body = "Body"
    email.Send
Set email = Nothing
```

I have reviewed many posts about this error but cannot find a matching solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are they all running the same version of outlook? What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you run the code in Outlook on a third machine?

Comment: @Marcelo: They are all running the same version of Outlook.
The error I am getting is "Error # -2147417843. Automation error.
An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call."

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: Sorry, I don't understand part of your question. I am running the code from within VBA. What do you mean "run the code in Outlook"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone, for the intial responses. Turns out what solved the problem is to use CDO for sending the email. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("cdo.message")
Set objConfig = CreateObject("cdo.configuration")
Set Flds = objConfig.Fields
Flds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
Flds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "myExchangeServerName"
Flds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  'basic (clear-text) authentication
Flds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myDomain\user@myDomain.com"
Flds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "myPassword"
Flds.Update
Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig
objMessage.To = "toEmail@someDomain.com"
objMessage.From = "fromEmail@someOtherDomain.com"
objMessage.Subject = "My Subject"
objMessage.Fields.Update
objMessage.HTMLBody = "<p><span style=""font-family: 'Calibri','Arial','sans-serif'"";>My Body Text</span></p>"
objMessage.AddAttachment "C:/path/filename.txt"
objMessage.Send
```

Answer (score 1):

When exactly is that code being executed? Is it running from a tray icon event handler by any chance?

Start up a timer, when the timer fires (you will be out of the incoming RPC call), run your code above.

Comment: The code is being executed by a high-performance software program called TeleForm Reader. It is simply stays open as an application on a server (not in the tray).
How can I start up a timer to run the code? I have been reading about that as a possible solution but haven't found a good URL that explains how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the third machine (called Reader) is doing some multi-threaded operations and that is why the error is coming up when trying to call Outlook from the third machine. I've never had to deal with threads before. Ugh! If I can't figure a way around, I might have to switch my approach and try sending the email using MAPI or by using direct SMTP.